# Cant post result from partial class method into datagrid

Tags: c#, linq, class, partial

I've been given a few questions to answer for an interview prior to going to it. I've been told to do as much research as I can and ask for answers where necessary. I've tried everything I can to get this working but I am at a loss. I've never done C# coding until yesterday so this is a big step into the world of the unknown.

The question I've been given is **Create a partial class for Course and add a property which only returns Students where their AverageSCore is greater than 70**

Now a brief introduction to what I've been given. The program consists of 4 tables linked together. They are Courses, Students, Teachers and Departments. Each table is represented as an Entity Course, Student, Teacher and Department. The code is set out into a number of different pages and the results are displayed on the webage Courses.Aspx. Now I've added a gridview (GridView1) to display the results of each question to show that its working.

They want me to add a Course partial class to a page called PartialClasses.cs and display the results on Courses.Aspx. Now the code I've been given for each page is

**Courses.Aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using School.Code.Web;
using School.Code;

namespace School
{
    public partial class Courses : BasePage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadData();
                                            }
        }

        public void LoadData()
        {

            IEnumerable<Course> courses = SchoolManager.GetAllCourses();

            //Bind list view with classes

        }
```

**PartialClasses.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace School.Code
{

    public partial class Teacher
    {
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Student : SchoolManager
    {
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
            }
        }

}
```

Now I know that this would produce the correct results

```
using (SchoolEntities ctx = new SchoolEntities())
{
    var results = from b in ctx.Students
                  where b.AverageScore > 70
                  select b;
    Array newarray = results.ToArray();
}
```

But I don't know how I add this to the PartialClass.cs page and then get the results into the Courses.Aspx page. Can anyone give me an example of how this is done please?

Answer (score 0):

Create Partial class for SchoolManager and add the last code snippet into it as readonly property or as a method, it is up to you.